# Do we have any way to connect HoloLens 2 with Azure Kinect DK without a machine in between?

Tags: hololens, azurekinect

Do we have any way to connect HoloLens 2 with Azure Kinect DK without a machine in between ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we should ensure having a PC or laptop between them. Azure Kinect DK only support Windows 10(x64) and Linux Ubuntu(x64), we can't deploy your Azure Kinect DK to HoloLens2 which with Windows Holographic OS. For more detailed information about the system requirements needed to deploy your Azure Kinect DK Please check this documentation: [Supported operating systems and architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/system-requirements)